# Welcome message to speak only after login in Django framework

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I have this fairly basic speech to text method in a python django project.
Now I would like to add a text to speech method in it too, where after anyone logs in, my applications speaks "Welcome < user >"

But the catch is, the "Welcome < user >" must be spoken in homepage and no intermediate page between login page and home page should be present(For efficiency purposes of course). This meant I should write my TTS in my home page. The problem here is, whenever I navigate to home page, it says "Welcome < user >". Which is ideally not supposed to happen.

Is there any workaround for this? Thank you

Comment: so you need the welcome msg only on first load ?

Comment: Set a cookie the first time you play the file, then check for it before you play it again.

Comment: @R.Haq yes. Welcome speech only after he logs in, not every time he goes to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to use a cookie to track the user as they navigate the website. The problem boils down to how to track whether the user is navigating to 
the home page from another page in your site.

However, a complete solution to your problem cannot be given without more details about how the website is set up. Are we talking about a flask website here? You don't give any details.

Comment: It's built on Django framework, and the module i'm using is
pyttsx3.

Comment: Please put that in your post and title. The text to speech library is not important for the problem at hand.